Is it possible that translators have mis-translated “anairei” in Hebrews 10:9?
My question is whether ἀναιρεῖ (anairei) should, or at least could, be translated as “take up”, as opposed to “take away” in Heb. 10:9. I have yet to find one translation that has “take up” in Heb 10:9.
“He takes away the first to establish the second”.
According to Thayers, “take up” is the primary meaning of anairei. However the most common usage of the word in the NT is to kill or “put to death”. Hebrews 10:9 is the only place in the NT where translators have “take away”. Also, the only place in the NT where translators have “take up” is Acts 7:21, when the daughter of pharaoh “took up” (anairei) Moses as a baby and raised him as her own.
Here’s the whole passage:
“Therefore, when Christ came into the world, he said:
“Sacrifice and offering you did not desire, but a body you prepared for me; with burnt offerings and sin offerings you were not pleased.
Then I said, ‘Here I am—it is written about me in the scroll—
I have come to do your will, my God.’
First he said, “Sacrifices and offerings, burnt offerings and sin offerings you did not desire, nor were you pleased with them”—though they were offered in accordance with the law. Then he said, “Here I am, I have come to do your will.” He takes away (anairei) the first to establish the second. And by that will, we have been made holy through the sacrifice of the body of Jesus Christ once for all.”
The issue that I have with the typical translation of anairei is that translators seem to mis-identify what the author is referring to as “the first” and “the second”. Is the author referring to the two sacrificial systems, and the old and new covenant? Or is he referring to two things mentioned in the quotation (from Psalms 40) that he just provided?
According to Thayers the word “then”, in the above case, is used as a “transition from one thing mentioned to another which could not take place before it.”, therefore the second thing mentioned in the psalms, “doing thy will” necessitates the first thing mentioned in the psalm having occurred— taking up “the body you have prepared for me.”
In my opinion the verse should be translated as: “He takes up the first (what was said of Him in the first part of the verse—the body prepared for Me), in order to establish the second, (what is said of Him in the second part of the verse—perform the will of the father).
With this understanding, the concluding verse makes much more sense, as he brings the “body” and “will”  (first and second) together:
“And by that will, we have been made holy through the sacrifice of the body of Jesus Christ once for all.”
Jesus “took up” the body prepared for him (the first) and thereby establishes, or performs, the will of God (the second) all the way to the cross, thus becoming the sacrifice that perfects forever those who draw near (v.14).

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below). Up-voted +1, for a well thought out, well researched and well expressed question.

This is an interesting question. Could be made some clearer by including the actual Greek word, which you could find here - https://biblehub.com/interlinear/hebrews/10-9.htm ... this Bible Hub site enables us to even click on the word in question to show how it's been used in other scripture and even usage during the same generalized time the scripture was written.  ἀναιρέω

Hebrews is discussing sacrifices not bodies.

@Dottard Isn't the body (of Jesus) the sacrifice?

One may take something up and away or one may take something up and bear it.  Christ took up a human nature and through it bore our sin away, as far as the East is from the west.

@MikeBorden - Jesus' body is not different from Jesus.

@Dottard— He is discussing sacrifices and a body; “a body you have prepared for me”, “… we have been made holy by the sacrifice of the body of Jesus Christ…”.

From my 1,700 page Special Edition, Liddel & Scott, 1854, anairew appears to me to be formed from ana and airew.
airw has meanings (Young/TR/KJV) of bear, carry, lift ; but predominantly take/take away. See further details below.
The concept of airew is to grasp or take or seize . . ..  only. It says nothing of the outcome.
It is the addition of ana which furnishes the dimension needed to complete the verbal idea. Thus to take up.
Ana, as always, adds the idea of 'up'ness.
See Daniel B Wallace's 'Beyond the Basics' p364 - ana 2.Spatial up, motion upwards.
Elsewhere in Greek usage generally and in scripture also, the word means to take up, particularly in its often use in the taking of life. The life goes upwards (animals' goes downwards in scripture) and the body falls to the ground and is buried there.
This is most true when God himself, providentially and also in judgment, takes up a life. The references on Biblehub attest to this usage predominantly in scripture.
I can see what you are saying. And it would seem to me, from the well established reference of Liddell & Scott (upon whom many, many lexicons have laid their foundation) that you are correct.
Of course, it will be an uphill struggle to be heard above the majority that follow tradition. It may well be that references will pour forth, disputing what you have said.
But I, myself, am listening to what you say, and am taking it seriously, due to the weight of evidence, thus far.
It seems to me that translators have not been sensitive enough to the Hebrew outlook on death, that the soul goes upwards (back to God) as the body is buried. Animal life descends into the earth.

Who knoweth the spirit of man that goeth upward, and the spirit of the beast that goeth downward to the earth?  [Ecclesiastes 3:21 KJV]

Thus death/slay/kill convey (to the Hebrew mind) 'take up'.
Robert Young lists the 23 biblical occurrences of anairew thusly :- kill 11 ; put to death 2 ; slay 8 ; take away 1 ; take up 1.
These are, of course, from Young, the TR/KJV references. Noticeably, on the only occasion when life is not taken up/away then the translation has been 'take up', notably, and then, we note questionably, 'take away' (the translation of the text under consideration).

EDIT IN REGARD TO COMMENT :
First, one must be sure of the textual meaning, before interpreting. But I can certainly see spiritual allusion in 'taking up'. For it is in the death of Christ, and in his resurrection and ascension, that the old is removed. The tables of stone are hidden in the ark, which (see the last few words of Genesis) is a coffer. Thus, death (a 'taking up') is the answer to all of it. Through a sacrificial death is the old covenant resolved in righteousness, making way for the new to be established. Only through the death of the Testator can this be. Till then, it is disallowed

What is your opinion of what is being referred to as “the first” and “the second”? Admittedly, for years I saw the referent as  the sacrifices under the law, vs. the the sacrifice of the new covenant—As if he is saying, “he takes away the first sacrifice (or Law) in order to establish the second. Now I am becoming increasingly more certain that the author is referring to what is being said in the text of Psalm that he references.

@TracyV First, one must be sure of the textual meaning, before interpreting. But I can certainly see spiritual allusion in 'taking up'. For it is in the death of Christ, and in his resurrection and ascension, that the old is removed. The tables of stone are hidden in the ark, which (see the last few words of Genesis) is a coffer. Thus, death (a 'taking up') is the answer to all of it. Through a sacrificial death is the old covenant resolved in righteousness, making way for the new to be established. Only through the death of the Testator can this be. Till then, it is disallowed.

@TracyV . . . . .  but I would go a little further and say 'He giveth up' the first, to establish the second. No man took it from him. He yielded up the body prepared for him. Being made sin (or 'effected' sin - it is poieo) he yielded his life, taking away the sin of the world, sin in the flesh ; eradicating sin in death. Thus all the law is silenced and the handwriting removed (exaleipho) taking it out of the midst of us.

“My question is whether ἀναιρεῖ (anairei) should, or at least could, be translated as ‘take up’, as opposed to “take away” in Heb. 10:9. I have yet to find one translation that has ‘take up’ in Heb 10:9.”
The reason why translations have not rendered anaireó (ἀναιρέω Strong’s 337) in Heb 10:9 as “take up” has to do with the fact that it is in the middle voice.
Thayer’s Greek Lexicon (emphasis added)


to take up, to lift up (from the ground); middle to take up for myself as value, to own (an exposed infant): Acts 7:21


Examining the occurrences of anaireó in the NT and the LXX, the instances where it means “take up” were all found to be in the Greek middle voice (NT: Acts 7:21; OT: Ex 2:5,10; Jos 4:3,5). Here are two examples:
Acts 7:21 KJV (interlinear)

Pharaoh's daughter took (aorist middle indicative) him up.

Numbers 16:37 (LXX)

take up (aorist middle imperative) the censers out of the blaze

“The issue that I have with the typical translation of anairei is that translators seem to mis-identify what the author is referring to as ‘the first’ and ‘the second’. Is the author referring to the two sacrificial systems, and the old and new covenant?
There are two things that are mentioned in the quotation:
Hebrew 10:5 NKJV

“Sacrifice and offering You did not desire, But a body You have
prepared for Me.”

In the active voice, anairei can mean “to take away” or “to kill/destroy.” In context, it could reference the death of the body and/or the taking away of the old system of sacrifices. The author contrasts the old and the new covenant, and the reference to “the first” and “the last” could pertain to these two covenants. But rather than a difference in sacrificial systems, what makes them distinct has to do with the fulfillment of God’s will.
Whereas the first covenant is characterized by disobedience and sin (vv.1-4), the last covenant is characterized by obedience to the will of God. A key or rather the key aspect of Jesus’ death is that it fulfills God’s will. Not a sacrifice in the same sense of the old covenant sacrifices, its true value lies in Jesus’ obedience (cf. Jn 10:17-18, Phil 2:8, Rom 5:18-19). He takes away the body (the first) so that he may fulfill the will of God (the last).

9 then He said, “Behold, I have come to do Your will, O
God.” He takes away the first that He may establish the second.
10 By that will we have been sanctified through the
offering of the body of Jesus Christ once for all.

What the quotation from Psalm 40 underscores is that God does not want sacrifices and offerings but obedience that comes from the heart. Christ takes away the first (system of sacrificial offerings) in order to establish the last (obedience to the will of God). Thus the death of Christ doesn’t inaugurate a different sacrificial system but a new era of obedience based on forgiveness and sanctifying grace.

16 “This is the covenant that I will make with them after
those days, says the Lord: I will put My laws into their hearts, and
in their minds I will write them,” 17 then He adds, “Their
sins and their lawless deeds I will remember no more.”

